# Is $2^x+x$ Exponential Function and $\log_2(x)+x$ a Logarithmic Function?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I just wonder can we call $2^x+x$  an exponential function or not?

With the same way of thinking is $\log_2(x)+x$  a logarithmic? 
or we can't have another term with theses functions holding a variable?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, note that from an algorithmic perspective we can call $2^x+x$ a function of _exponential growth_, because that captures how quickly the function grows as $x$ goes to infinity.  OTOH, we _can't_ call $\log_2(x)+x$ a function of logarithmic growth; can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way si to say that $2^x + x$ is the sum of an ***exponential and a linear*** function and similarly for $\log_2 x + x$.